# Add filter option on each column of the data displayed in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, filter

I am generating a table in SSRS based on the selection made by the user on two filters: Filter1 and Filter2 (say). The table so displayed has 10 columns and I wish to add filter option listing all available values for that column for all 10 columns.

Basically, I am trying to replicate the Excel functionality of filtering down data on each and every column.

Please note that I tried creating a new data set and a parameter taking all distinct values for a particular variable. However, I am still not able to get the desired results by filter the tablix on that parameter

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make a new dataset that is a smaller version of your main dataset. It would need to return all potential values for the column(s) you want to filter in a single column to be used in a parameter.

Without seeing the design of the report or the dataset itself it's quite hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  My table is something like: Var1 -Var 2 - Var3 - Var4. I am asking the user to filter based on Var 1 and Var2. Now the output is a table containing variables Var1-Var4. Let's say Var4 is gender, so in the output table I want to allow the user to filter the table down based on gender = M/F